# Class Strings and print functions

Tags: python, string, class, printing

I'm working on a text based game and I've done this so far:

```
class Map():
    room1 = ('sampletext')

print(Map(room1))
```

but then i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/Text.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(Map(room1))
NameError: name 'room1' is not defined
```

and I don't understand why the string from the variable isn't being printed because i am calling the class, but it says that the variable isn't recognized as a variable in the code. I want feedback so I can finish up this game.

Comment: Why do you have `()` around `'sampletext'`? If you're trying to make a tuple with one element, you need a comma: `('sampletext',)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Map():
    room1 = ('sampletext')

print(Map.room1)
```

Output:

```
sampletext
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you can't call a class.  You can call a class method, or call a method on an instance of the class.  The syntax

```
Map(room1)
```

attempts to create an instance (object) of `Map`, given the initialization argument `room1`, which should be a local variable.

With the class definition you've given, I think that the proper syntax is

```
print(Map.room1)
```

which references the value of the class attribute `room1`.